# Determining which gencode (compute_, arch_) values I need for nvcc - within CMake

Tags: cuda, cmake, build-automation, detection

I'm using CMake as a build system for my code, which involves CUDA. I was thinking of automating the task of deciding which `compute_XX` and `arch_XX` I need to to pass to my nvcc in order to compile for the GPU(s) on my current machine.

- Is there a way to do this:

  1. With the NVIDIA GPU deployment kit?
  2. Without the NVIDIA GPU deployment kit?
- Does CMake's `FindCUDA` help you in determining the values for these switches?

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly you envision. Do you want CMake to detect all NVIDIA GPUs in your *build* system and query the compute capability of each one (e.g. by invoking `nvidia-smi`), then build a list of `-arch` flags based on the results? Especially in a cluster, the build system may contain a completely different GPU than the GPU-enabled cluster nodes, or even no GPU at all.

Comment: You can write script that determines yours arch and than running build with necessary options or you can pass all possible arch variants to compiler, in that case needed code for yours gpu will be determined and loaded in runtime

Comment: @njuffa: Well, by default, you build for the system you're building on, so - I guess, yes. And even if it just looked at some environment variable it expects to see this info in, that would also be something.

Comment: @vlad1slav: I know I can do that, but that would be reinventing the wheel. Doesn't such a script exist already? And shouldn't it be a(n optional) part of FindCUDA ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`cuda_select_nvcc_arch_flags()`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/FindCUDA/select_compute_arch.cmake) macro in the [FindCUDA](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDA.html) module for this without any additional scripts when using CMake 3.7 or newer.

```
include(FindCUDA)
set(CUDA_ARCH_LIST Auto CACHE STRING
    "List of CUDA architectures (e.g. Pascal, Volta, etc) or \
compute capability versions (6.1, 7.0, etc) to generate code for. \
Set to Auto for automatic detection (default)."
)
cuda_select_nvcc_arch_flags(CUDA_ARCH_FLAGS ${CUDA_ARCH_LIST})
list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_ARCH_FLAGS})
```

The above sets `CUDA_ARCH_FLAGS` to `-gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61` on my machine, for example.
The `CUDA_ARCH_LIST` cache variable can be configured by the user to generate code for specific compute capabilites instead of automatic detection.

Note: the FindCUDA module has been deprecated since CMake 3.10. However, no equivalent alternative to the `cuda_select_nvcc_arch_flags()` macro appears to be provided yet in the latest CMake release (v3.14). See this [relevant issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19199) at the CMake issue tracker for further details.

Comment: Isn't the use of FindCUDA deprecated in CMake 3.8?

Comment: It is, indeed. There does not appear to be any relevant substitute for it yet, though, as you already noticed. Thanks for creating a relevant issue at the CMake issue tracker! I included a link to it in the answer.

Comment: @einpoklum try `find_package( CUDA REQUIRED)` instead

Comment: @schuess: Well, I've moved own from 3.8... and soon, in 3.24, Kitware will have [fixed the bug I filed about this](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22375) and all will be well.

Answer (score 9):

My strategy has been to compile and run a bash script that probes the card and returns the gencode for cmake. Inspiration came from [University of Chicago's SLURM](https://howto.cs.uchicago.edu/techstaff:slurm#example1). To handle errors or multiple gpus or other circumstances, modify as necessary.

In your project folder create a file cudaComputeVersion.bash and ensure it is executable from the shell. Into this file put:

```
#!/bin/bash

# create a 'here document' that is code we compile and use to probe the card
cat << EOF > /tmp/cudaComputeVersion.cu
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
cudaDeviceProp prop;
cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop,0);
int v = prop.major * 10 + prop.minor;
printf("-gencode arch=compute_%d,code=sm_%d\n",v,v);
}
EOF

# probe the card and cleanup
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc /tmp/cudaComputeVersion.cu -o /tmp/cudaComputeVersion
/tmp/cudaComputeVersion
rm /tmp/cudaComputeVersion.cu
rm /tmp/cudaComputeVersion
```

And in your CMakeLists.txt put:

```
# at cmake-build-time, probe the card and set a cmake variable
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cudaComputeVersion.bash OUTPUT_VARIABLE GENCODE)
# at project-compile-time, include the gencode into the compile options
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}; "${GENCODE}")

# this makes CMake all chatty and allows you to see that GENCODE was set correctly
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE TRUE)
```

cheers

Comment: Nice... I'll try that next week and see. For now, +1. However... I would need to make the bash script use the FindCUDA-obtained path of `nvcc`.

Comment: @einpoklum Ya, I know I sort of didn't cover that. It may be possible to pass an arg to the script... but I have not tried it.

Comment: So, I've hacked at it for a bit and come up with a (hopefully) better version which you might also appreciate, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

A slight improvement over @orthopteroid's answer, which pretty much ensures a unique temporary file is generated, and only requires one instead of two temporary files.

The following goes into `scripts/get_cuda_sm.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash 
#
# Prints the compute capability of the first CUDA device installed
# on the system, or alternatively the device whose index is the
# first command-line argument

device_index=${1:-0}
timestamp=$(date +%s.%N)
gcc_binary=$(which g++)
gcc_binary=${gcc_binary:-g++}
cuda_root=${CUDA_DIR:-/usr/local/cuda}
CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS=${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS:-${cuda_root}/include}
CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY=${CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY:-${cuda_root}/lib64/libcudart.so}
generated_binary="/tmp/cuda-compute-version-helper-$$-$timestamp"
# create a 'here document' that is code we compile and use to probe the card
source_code="$(cat << EOF 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

int main()
{
        cudaDeviceProp prop;
        cudaError_t status;
        int device_count;
        status = cudaGetDeviceCount(&device_count);
        if (status != cudaSuccess) { 
                fprintf(stderr,"cudaGetDeviceCount() failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(status)); 
                return -1;
        }
        if (${device_index} >= device_count) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Specified device index %d exceeds the maximum (the device count on this system is %d)\n", ${device_index}, device_count);
                return -1;
        }
        status = cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, ${device_index});
        if (status != cudaSuccess) { 
                fprintf(stderr,"cudaGetDeviceProperties() for device ${device_index} failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(status)); 
                return -1;
        }
        int v = prop.major * 10 + prop.minor;
        printf("%d\\n", v);
}
EOF
)"
echo "$source_code" | $gcc_binary -x c++ -I"$CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS" -o "$generated_binary" - -x none "$CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY"

# probe the card and cleanup

$generated_binary
rm $generated_binary
```

and the following goes into `CMakeLists.txt` or a CMake module:

```
if (NOT CUDA_TARGET_COMPUTE_CAPABILITY)
    if("$ENV{CUDA_SM}" STREQUAL "")
        set(ENV{CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS} "${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
        set(ENV{CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY} "${CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY}")
        set(ENV{CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
        execute_process(COMMAND 
            bash -c "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/get_cuda_sm.sh" 
            OUTPUT_VARIABLE CUDA_TARGET_COMPUTE_CAPABILITY_)
    else()
        set(CUDA_TARGET_COMPUTE_CAPABILITY_ $ENV{CUDA_SM})
    endif()

    set(CUDA_TARGET_COMPUTE_CAPABILITY "${CUDA_TARGET_COMPUTE_CAPABILITY_}" 
        CACHE STRING "CUDA compute capability of the (first) CUDA device on \
        the system, in XY format (like the X.Y format but no dot); see table \
        of features and capabilities by capability X.Y value at \
        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Version_features_and_specifications")

    execute_process(COMMAND 
        bash -c "echo -n $(echo ${CUDA_TARGET_COMPUTE_CAPABILITY})" 
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE CUDA_TARGET_COMPUTE_CAPABILITY)
    execute_process(COMMAND 
        bash -c "echo ${CUDA_TARGET_COMPUTE_CAPABILITY} | sed 's/^\\([0-9]\\)\\([0-9]\\)/\\1.\\2/;' | xargs echo -n" 
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE FORMATTED_COMPUTE_CAPABILITY)

    message(STATUS 
        "CUDA device-side code will assume compute capability \
        ${FORMATTED_COMPUTE_CAPABILITY}")
endif()

set(CUDA_GENCODE
    "arch=compute_${CUDA_TARGET_COMPUTE_CAPABILITY}, code=compute_${CUDA_TARGET_COMPUTE_CAPABILITY}")
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -gencode ${CUDA_GENCODE} )
```

Comment: @orthopteroid: If you like it, you can: 1. Use it and see if there aren't bugs / corner case I've missed and 2. Upvote...

Comment: @orthopteroid: Also, I think it would work with just piping the source to the GCC binary like you did; I'm just used to more of a single-assignment style.

Comment: I tried using this and am getting this error from cmake:
```bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token '|'
bash: -c: line 1: ` | sed 's/^\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\)/\1.\2/;' | xargs echo -n'
Building for Compute Capability 61```

Comment: @tylerjw: Possibly you had empty ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS} or `${CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY}`. You need to "find CUDA". If not - you need to more carefully check where/how this fails. But regardless - see edit.

Comment: Missing the open quotes on the set CUDA_GENCODE line and the newline in the string causes an error in cmake.  Not enough of a change for an edit.  Thank you for the update, it works for me now.

Comment: @tylerjw: You mean like I just changed in the edit I've made? If so, thanks. I guess quotes never hurt.