# Make gcc -x somelang link with an arbitrary library file without -L'ing its directory?

Tags: gcc, command-line, linker, libraries

I have a source file which is named `foo.bar` and for the purpose of this question cannot be renamed or linked to. Say it's a C++ source file. Now, I want to compile it and link it, in the same command, using a library at `path/to/weird_lib_file`. Now, if the source filename was `foo.cpp`, I could do:

```
gcc -o foo foo.cpp /path/to/weird_lib_file
```

and that would work. But if I write

```
gcc -o foo -x c++ foo.cpp /path/to/weird_lib_file
```

it doesn't work. Now, I could do

```
gcc -o foo -x c++ foo.cpp -L /path/to/ -l:weird_lib_file
```

as suggested here:

[How to link using GCC without -l nor hardcoding path for a library that does not follow the libNAME.so naming convention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207069/how-to-link-using-gcc-without-l-nor-hardcoding-path-for-a-library-that-does-not)

but for some reason which I will also not go into, I would rather not -L that folder. Can I still force GCC to link against that individual library file somehow? It seems that `-l:/path/to/weird_lib_file` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not `-L` the path to the library you may
specify the library by an absolute or relative pathname. In the
latter case, whatever the library is called, it will be taken
as a linker input unless it has an extension that makes it
appear to be a source file. Thus

```
gcc -o prog main.c foo.xyz
```

will compile `main.c` and link `main.o` with the library `./foo.xyz` if in
fact it is one, whether static or shared, that can satisfy the linkage.

**Later**

(Before editing, the question did not mention the `-x` option).

The introduction of the `-x` option as in:

```
gcc -o prog -x c++ main.cpp foo.xyz
```

provokes an error like:

```
foo.xyz:2:1: error: stray ‘`’ in program
 /               0           0     0     0       16        `
 ^
foo.xyz:3:1: warning: null character(s) ignored
       T_Z3foov foo.o/          0           0     0     644     1544      `
 ^
foo.xyz:3:4: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
       T_Z3foov foo.o/          0           0     0     644     1544      `
    ^
...
...
```

even when `foo.xyz` is in fact a library that can satisfy the linkage,
going by an unorthodox name.

As it must, because `-x c++` directs gcc to construe subsequent input files
as C++ source until further notice. As [documented](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options)

> -x language
>
> Specify explicitly the language for the following input files (rather than 
>   letting the compiler choose a default based on the file name suffix).
>   This option applies to all following input files until the next -x option.

And further notice never comes.

Of course, this does not happen in the case, e.g. of:

```
gcc -o prog -x c++ main.cpp -L. -l:foo.xyz
```

because `-l:foo.xyz` isn't an input file but a linker option (which, in
conjunction with `-L.`, specifies an input file).

To avoid this outcome you must drop the insistence that `foo.xyz` is
a C++ source file by cancelling `-x c++` before it is reached, like:

```
gcc -o prog -x c++ main.cpp -x none foo.xyz
```

As documented:

> -x none
>
> Turn off any specification of a language, so that subsequent files are handled 
>   according to their file name suffixes (as they are if -x has not been used at all).

Comment: That doesn't work for me... hmmm... maybe I dropped some switches from the example above. Let me edit that.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I didn't realize I could -x twice. So, in case you're interested, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40665580/1593077) is the motivation (although actually the library name does end with `.so`).